# The Mathematics of Symbol Recognition.

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, soft-question, applications, knot-theory

I wonder what Mathematics is  behind handwriting and symbol recognition.

I was using Detexify just now and it struck me that a distinction could be made between $\varsigma$ (a variant of the Greek letter sigma), $\zeta$ (the Greek letter zeta), and $\xi$ (the Greek letter xi).

I was thinking that it'd be some combination of Topology, Graph Theory, and Knot Theory.

> How do such recognition things like Detexify work, mathematically speaking?

A detailed answer would be great.

Comment: I don't know about detexify in particular, but often image recognition is done by convolutional neural networks.

Comment: Character recognition is done through wavelet transforms. I have seen many small engineering examples of this and none of them used any machine learning techniques at all, just pure signal processing and some if-else statements

Comment: I know that support vector machines (SVMs) are used sometimes for handwritten character recognition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine). In general, this falls under a combination of (1) a classification problem which is something (a topic in machine learning and data mining) and (2) image processing (which are sometimes used to "pre-process" the image so that suitable data-mining/machine-learning techniques can be applied to them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Detexify's implementation is explained here: https://gist.github.com/kirel/149896 Briefly, it is a [$k$-nearest neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) classifier with hand-tuned features. Nothing fancy, no topology:

> The features I use (at the time of writing) are number of strokes, point density and directional features.

Answer (score 1):

You might explore [MyScript Math](https://developer.myscript.com/math):

[image: MathScript]