# What type of Mathematics, if any, is this? (On curiosities associated with a logo.)

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, knot-theory, directed-graphs, winding-number

*I'm not sure whether I have articulated my curiosity well enough here. Please, therefore, bear with me if I need to edit the question, and please forgive me if this is otherwise a nonsense question that cannot be salvaged.*

Consider the following Linkin Park logo:

[image]

*(NB: I'm not sure whether permission is needed to share this logo; if it is needed, let me know and then I'll delete it.)*

The logo is one continuous line in the shape of a circle that, if you start at the top end, draws what is nearly a semicircle,  before tracing out a stylised $P$, which leads to a stylised $L$, which, in turn, becomes the rest of the circle.

What I have described is a counterclockwise orientation that writes the $P$ and the $L$ *in that order* - backwards in standard English - and if you wanted to write $L$ then $P$ (by tracing out the logo), then you would need to start at the bottom end (although also counterclockwise).

> What type of Mathematics, if any, describes/studies these different orientations of similar images?

Some thoughts:

- It might not be graph theory. There is a direction to what is going on here, something an undirected graph doesn't take into account.
- It's not knot theory. The logo is not a knot.
- It might be a directed graph.
- I'm aware of the notion of a [winding number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number), something I encountered in my undergraduate days during my complex analysis and my special functions modules. It seems related.
- The question [The Mathematics of Symbol Recognition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2245617/104041) of mine springs to mind, although I'm not sure why.
- We could, I suppose, ignore the perimeter, leaving us with just the $L$ and the $P$, although that would switch top-to-bottom to bottom-to-top, and *vice versa*.

The order of the $L$ and the $P$ is what I'm interested in most of all here. This is motivated by considering how I would draw the logo.

As you can see, this is a difficult thing to search for online (especially because it's still a little fuzzy to me).

Please help :)

Comment: Do you have a second example?  It is very difficult to extrapolate from one data point.

Comment: That's a good point. Thank you. I'll see what I can find, @JBL.

Comment: I don't really see an obvious or interesting math angle. The near half-circles allow for the apparent reversal or "natural order." But even the "natural order" isn't really a mathematical thing, just our impression of where we expect to start writing letters and the order we expect to write them.